# how to read bytes bigger than 127 in java?

Tags: java, byte, arrays

alright, so my code to read bytes into a int is like so:

```
int offset = (byte << 16) | (byte2  << 8) | byte3;
```

And it's reading the bytes "00 00 be" as -66.

How do I read it as the 190 it's meant to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
byte b = -66;
int i = b & 0xff;
```

Comment: that worked. I'll be accepting this answer as soon as I can ^_^ thank you.

Comment: an explanation perhaps: this works because the `0xff` literal is an int, not a byte. Otherwise the bitwise AND with `0xff` would yield the same byte again.

Comment: yup. The same thing works for dealing w/ shorts, just do an `& 0xffff`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    byte b = -66;
    int i = b < 0 ? b + 256 : b;
```

It might be useful declare helper function for this.